# Display All Geomap Markers within Map Viewport

Tags: javascript, maps, geocoding

a little guidance would be appreciated.

I am trying to ensure any and all map Markers are displayed within the map viewport; in other words I am asking Maps to zoom to the nearest zoom value to include all specified Markers.

I have code that functions as expected when pulled from a database and populates a localised area. I then had to expand the viewport area to encompass a country with all Markers showing within a boundary described by the bounds setting.

I am obviously missing something, since when I request .fitBounds - unless there is a single Marker - I get a world (0) zoom and consequently all markers overlapping until zoom.

Here is my script in Classic ASP and Javascript:

```
        var map;
        var markers = [];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        function initializeMapping() {
            var txtGeocode = document.getElementById("txtGeocode").value;
            var codepair=txtGeocode.split(",");
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, panControl: true, zoomControl: true, gestureHandling: 'greedy', center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(codepair[0]), parseFloat(codepair[1]))
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);

            <%for m = 0 to markercount
                imgCountQry = "select lngPhotoID from tblImages where lngPropertyID = " & markerarr(8,m)
                Set imgrs = conn.execute(imgCountQry)
                if imgrs.bof and imgrs.eof then
                    imgcount = 0
                else
                    imgarr = imgrs.getrows
                    imgcount = ubound(imgarr,2) + 1
                end if
                imgrs.close
                set imgrs = nothing
                fullAddress = markerarr(1,m) & ", " & markerarr(3,m) & ", " & markerarr(4,m) & ", " & markerarr(5,m)
                imageIDtmb = left(markerarr(9,m),len(markerarr(9,m))-4) & "_med.jpg"
                markertext = "<div class='mapballoon'><p>" & fullAddress & "<a target='_blank' href='property-details.asp?pid=" & markerarr(8,m) & "'><br />Visit Property</a><br /><span><b>[&nbsp; ]<i>" & imgcount & "</i></b><img src='adimages/" & imageIDtmb & "' width='250' /></span></p></div>"%>
                createMarker(<%=markerarr(7,m)%>, "<%=markertext%>");
            <%next%>

            fitMarkers()
        };

        function createMarker(lat,lng, html) {
            var newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng), map: map, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, title: 'Click to see property', icon: 'images/home-2.png'});
            markers.push(newmarker);

            newmarker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: 250, content: html});

            google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'click', function() {
            hideInfowindows(map);
            newmarker.setOpacity(0.5);
            this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
            });
        }

        function fitMarkers() {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
            }

            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
//          map.getBounds(map.fitBounds(bounds));
//          map.getBounds(map.getBounds(bounds));
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            map.getZoom();      
        }
```

Believe me, I have spent all night looking for solutions to my obvious poor understanding of Google Maps but I am now exhausted and must ask for help.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: Can you give an example of the data that comes out of the database?

Comment: The database is not the issue. As can bee sen here - [link]http://evisplace.com/property-rentals.asp

Comment: Use Search visually button.

Comment: It was more a thought that maybe one of the coordinates in your database is outside the borders of the world.

Comment: Good point. I grab the geo coords from Google' API, so they should be good to go but as far as I can see they all exist within the latlong boundaries. But good call.

Comment: Also , are you sure that the first value you get is in fact the lat and not the lng? by switching them up it could end up outside the boundaries as well.

Comment: I've just verified all latlong coords with their respective postal address in the database and they correlate. Now I'll see what map.fitBounds(bounds) is pulling. Incidentally, I have tried getBounds but with similar challenges.

Answer (score 2):

This might help. Create a new bounds object:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Then extend the bounds by each marker object.

```
bounds.extend(myLatLng);
```

Then apply the bounds to the map:

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: I have incorporated both in the JS.

Comment: Just make sure the **.getPosition()** function is returning the correct value sometimes it can be troublesome

Comment: Okay. I'll parse the coords and dump them. Right now, life is proving troublesome. I'm setting up a dedicated server and installing components. So please forgive if my responses are tardy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, hang in there. You're doing great. Sorry if I can't be of more help. I'm still a junior and answering questions is a good way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I am now going to propose the classic programmers solution: apply logic - but with a glass of scotch because I am seriously cheesed with this.

I have tried:-

1. incorporating the bounds.extend(markers[i]) into the create marker loop ... nope, no joy
2. incorporating a delay before the fitBounds statement ... ditto;
3. incorporating v2 mapping getZoomByBounds discarded property as a function ... ditto.
4. forcibly setting map.setZoom(xx) to any arbitrary level.
5. Cyanide capsules - but it seems I'm immortal.

Come on somebody, I could really do with an angle on this. It's all to do with setting a zoom level or ensuring that the map.fitBounds(bounds) call sees it's outer limits (da-da-da-da-da...).

Anyway. I believe the challenge is defining the area in which the viewport is bounded because if I centre my cursor and zoom I can bound the markers dynamically, suggesting that the viewport is centred to the bounds array...

I could really do with some more assistance here.

/Mike